# Solution of equation $\tan x+\sin^2x=\cot^2 x$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve for $x$

> $\tan x+\sin^2x=\cot^2 x$

I converted everything into $\tan$ but equation is quite complex to solve manually,

$t^5+t^4+t^3=t^2+1$ where $\tan x=t$

Can someone suggest some other method?

Comment: The rational root theorem fails here and Mathematica does not give a very nice output. I am inclined to think it does not get much simpler than what you have written.

Comment: Mathematica is suggesting that your polynomial is slightly off, but perhaps it is wrong. It is suggesting that $t$ solves $t^5+t^4-2t^3-t^2+3t-1=0$.

Comment: I think your polynomial is correct. It only has one real zero, so a) if you can _prove_ that, then b) you can focus efforts on numerical methods for estimating that one value of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Given the original equation it is clear that even if there were more than one root you only want positive roots.

Then Descartes' rule of signs applied to $P(t)=t^5+t^4+t^3-t^2-1$ tells you there is exactly one positive root.

Also it is clear that as $P(t)$ changes signs between $0$ and $1$ the root lies between $0$ and $1$. Then applying the bisection method gives the root is at $t\approx 0.87445$.

(The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/) does not turn up any sensible relations that the root or its inverse tangent, both to 10 digits, satisfy)

Comment: but according to graph $x=0.719$ is a root and not only this but a lots of solution

Comment: Your polynomial gives a solution for $t=tan(x)$ which gives as the first solution for $x=\arctan(0.87445)= 0.71852$. But as $\tan$ is periodic with period $\pi$ there are an infinite number of solutions.